# Передача значений между классами из вложенных функций

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, tkinter

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, скорее всего решение простое и для кого-то очевидное, но я уже несколько часов не могу сообразить, как вернуть значение вложенной функции из импортированного модуля. Немного подробнее: есть интерфейс, написанный на tkinter и состоящий из нескольких модулей.

В упрощенном варианте это файл main и импортированный файл result с классом Search_Result.

В main создается фрейм Variables, который отображает результаты вызова различных функций. За отображение значений в этом фрейме отвечает класс Search_Result. Так же, при клике по значению во фрейме Variables, вызывается функция test_fx, которая выводит в консоль значение по которому щелкнули.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос заключается в том, что мне необходимо вернуть значение функции test_fx из класса Search_Result в модуль main, подскажите как это сделать?

Модуль Main

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from test_scripts.result import Search_Result

class MainInterface:

    def __init__(self):

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("300x200")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        user_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=30)
        user_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)

        find_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Find", command=lambda: user_request())
        find_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

        var_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, width=200, height=100, text="Variables", relief=tk.RIDGE)
        var_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
        var_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        def user_request():

            request = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
            Search_Result.search_result_fx(var_frame, request)

            # Как получить тут значение text, по которому щелкнули мышкой ?????????

program = MainInterface()
program.window.mainloop()
```

Код модуля Search_Result

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Search_Result(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.search_result_fx()

    def search_result_fx(self, request):
        row = 0

        for key, value in request.items():  # Dict
            row += 1
            formated_text = " {}{}{}".format(key, " - ", value)
            found_result_label = ttk.Label(self, text=formated_text)
            found_result_label.bind("<Button-1>", func=lambda event, text=key: test_fx(text))
            found_result_label.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        def test_fx(text):

            """
            Необходимо вернуть отсюда значение text в модуль main
            """
            print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

В методе test_fx записываете результат поиска в какое-то поле:

```
def test_fx(self, text):
    """
    Необходимо вернуть отсюда значение text в модуль main
    """
    self.result = text  # вместо text нужно записывать результат поиска
```

В `__init__` это поле желательно заранее обнулить.

Далее, `Search_Result` - это у вас класс виджета, он у вас должен быть размещен на главном окне (или вообще убрать у него свойства виджета).

В главном окне нужно создать объект класса `Search_Result` (у вас объект не создается, просто идет обращение к методам класса), потом после поиска брать результат из поля объекта `result`:

```
def create_widgets(self):

    self.window['padx'] = 10
    self.window['pady'] = 10

    user_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=30)
    user_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)

    find_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Find", command=lambda: user_request())
    find_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

    var_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, width=200, height=100, text="Variables", relief=tk.RIDGE)
    var_frame.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
    var_frame.grid_propagate(False)

    self.search_result = Search_Result(var_frame)
    self.search_result.pack()

    def user_request():
        request = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
        self.search_result.search_result_fx(var_frame, request)
        print(self.search_result.result)  # выводим результат поиска
```

---

Добавил полный пример.

Идея осталась та же: при клике мышью записываем выбранный результат в поле объекта `search_result`. В моем варианте это полноценный фрейм, добавленный внутрь родительского объекта `var_frame`. В вашем коде вы не создаете настоящий объект класса `Search_Result`, а используете только сам голый класс, в его метод вместо `self` подсовываете другой существующий объект `var_frame`. Это как бы не очень "честно". Правильно - отнаследоваться от класса фрейма, добавить нужные методы, создавать объект нового класса.

Также обратите внимание на прочие мелкие переделки кода и комментарии в коде.

```
class Search_Result(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Здесь оставляем только инициализацию
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.selected = None  # изначально ничего не выбрано

    def search_result_fx(self, request: dict):
        for row, (key, value) in enumerate(request.items()):
            formated_text = " {} - {}".format(key, value)
            found_result_label = ttk.Label(self, text=formated_text)
            found_result_label.bind("<Button-1>", func=lambda event, text=key: test_fx(text))
            found_result_label.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        def test_fx(text):
            print('Selected:', text)
            self.selected = text
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from test_scripts.result import Search_Result

class MainInterface:

    def __init__(self):

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("300x200")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        user_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=30)
        user_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)

        def user_request():
            request = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
            search_result.search_result_fx(request)
            # Как получить тут значение text, по которому щелкнули мышкой ?????????
            # Ответ: тут никак, потому что поиск выполнен, но пользователь еще не щелкнул мышкой по нужному результату, поэтому
            print('Result:', search_result.selected)  # выведет None

        find_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Find", command=user_request)  # <- просто имя функции вместо лямбды, но саму функцию пришлось переместить выше
        find_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

        # Но можно добавить еще одну кнопку "вывести результат":
        show_result = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Show result", command=lambda: print('Result:', search_result.selected))
        show_result.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='N')

        var_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, width=200, height=100, text="Variables", relief=tk.RIDGE)
        var_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
        var_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        search_result = Search_Result(var_frame)  # создаем фрейм, указываем родительский элемент управления
        search_result.pack()


program = MainInterface()
program.window.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: А можно Вас попросить прислать измененный код файлов, а то я с программированием и Python всего пару месяцев знаком, и если честно половину Вашего описания не понял. Учусь потихоньку, некоторые вещи для меня не совсем очевидны :)
Я попробовал изменить код, но есть проблемы с определением имен

Comment: Добавил полный пример

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш пример, теперь стало более понятно, хоть и данное решение не совсем мне подходит, изначальная идея была уйти от посторения кода Search_Result в каждом модуле. Если сделать все в main, то можно обойтись и без кнопки ShowResult, но у меня слишком много модулей и не хотелось повторяться.

Comment: Другой вариант - при инициализации передавать в объект Search_Result колбэк-функцию, которая будет вызваться вместо test_fx при нажатии на лэйбл.

Comment: А колбэк функция должна быть в main?

Comment: Да, в главном модуле, передаем ее при иницализации в `Search_Result`, и она вызывается при клике на лейбл внутри `Search_Result`.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае так. Функция в вызываемом модуле Search_Result:

```
def fx():
    // код
    return result
```

В вызывающем модуле:

```
   x = Search_Result.fx()
```

В итоге `x` получит значение `result`.

Comment: Не совсем бесмысслено: суть в том, что в Main должна вызываться функция с параметром text
new_request = some_fx(text), но мне надо как-то передать text по щелчку мыши в эту функцию

Comment: Я и говорю - чтобы получить text, нужно вызвать функцию передав в неё этот самый text, который мы хотим получить.

Comment: Тогда можно сделать так, функция 
def test_fx(text):
new_request = some_fx(text), это работает, но как вернуть new_request в main

Comment: Как обычно: возвращать из функции return new_request и вызывать функцию в main.

Comment: Так не работает,  def test_fx(text) вызывается автоматом при ПКМ, и какие-то результаты будут присвоены new_request, но они не видны из другого модуля

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что надо сделать в функции  def user_request():
            request = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
            Search_Result.search_result_fx(var_frame, request) чтобы получить тут значение text

Comment: Чтобы из функции что-то куда-то передать, нужно эту функцию вызвать там, куда передаем. Можете писать значения в переменную и потом читать ее из main. Но в любом случае придется переделывать тут или там и потребуются активные действия из main.

Comment: так в этом и состоит мой вопрос, что надо такого сделать в main, чтобы получить результаты test_fx(text) из Search_Result

Comment: У text_fx нет результатов, эта функция просто печатает переданный ей извне текст.

Comment: Хорошо, допустим text_fx не печатает текст, а вызывает другую функцию с параметром text и ей возвращается список, словарь, что угодно. Это будет выглядить new_request = fx(text), new_request содержит данные, которые необходиомо прикрутить к интерфейсу в модуле main,

Comment: Это решение не работает, если я Вас правильно понял, то def fx(text) это вложенная функция в Search_result_fx(), и при вызове я получаю ошибку x = Search_Result.fx()
AttributeError: type object 'Search_Result' has no attribute 'fx'

Comment: Если вложена, можно выложить. Или добавить переменную, как в соседнем ответе.